# How to add a Class to the body element when a new blog post is published?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a class to my html (either the body tag or another element) after a new blog post is published, and then remove the class after a number of days.

New blog post published >> 
Body gets class new-post >> 
3 days later >> 
new-post is removed from the body.

Any ideas how I would achieve this.

Thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: Would there be new blog posts during that three days, or just on new post every 3 days?

Comment: There would potentially be new posts added within those three days.  So yes, I'd need to check if the class has already been added.

Comment: So potentially the body class `new-post` could be on the body indefinitely?   So would it make sense to just say "if the newest post is less than 3 days old, add the body class"?

Comment: that could work yeah.

Comment: I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?php

    $blogPosts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'status' => 'publish',));
    $newestPostDate = get_the_time('U',$blogPosts[0]->ID);
    $threeDaysOld = strtotime('-36 hours');

    if ($newestPostDate > $threeDaysOld) { ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                if (jQuery('body').hasClass('new-post')) {
                    // do nothing
                } else {
                    jQuery('body').addClass('new-post');        
                }
            });
        </script>

    <?php } ?>
```

You could change `'post_type' => 'post'` to any post type you want, currently it is set to get the main blog posts.  This piece of code with get the newest post, and check if its date is more than 3 days old.  If the date is less than 3 days old, it will check if the body already has the class `new-post`, if it does it will do nothing, but if it does not it will add the class.  It would fire each time the page loads that you have this code on.  Place it on the page template file you want it to check for anywhere after the opening HTML `<body>` tag.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Awesome... I'm probably not going to get a chance to try this out today, but tomorrow I'll be sure to take a look... Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome, if it answers your questions please accept it when you have tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

Write an if conditional against the_date() to check if it is less than today - 3 days